# Backbone Model on change save - infinite loop?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm clearly missing the obvious here, but it's been a long day already.

The following code creates an infinite loop in the browser:

```
M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("ModelName"),
    initialize: function() {
        this.on("change", this.save, this);
    }
});
```

While the following code works fine:

```
M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("ModelName"),
    initialize: function() {
        this.on("change", this.modelChanged, this);
    },
    modelChanged: function() {
        this.save();
    }
});
```

What's the difference?

(Yes, I'm using local storage for a model rather than a collection, but the model is a singleton that doesn't exist in a collection.)

Comment: Did you tried to use the `silent: true` option so that your save does not trigger the Change event ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `change` event passes arguments to its handler, and if `save` is called with arguments, it applies them as new attributes to the model, and causes a `change` event (which passes attributes to save... which causes a change... etc)

Comment: Sweet! I knew it was obvious. Thanks! (From the docs: "Calling save with new attributes will cause a 'change' event immediately")